# Assigning a dataframe columns to a for loop syntax question

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to set the columns of a data frame to lower case like this:

```
df.columns = [i.lower() for i in df.columns]
```

Why are the brackets necessary for this to work? Sorry I'm a bit hazy on the syntax. Is there a better alternative to what I'm doing?

Comment: Look up list comprehension. An alternative is `df.columns.str.lower()`

Comment: Thank you "list comprehension" was the phrase I was looking for

Comment: @NimbleTortoise, You don't need Unnecessary list comprehension for this case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different direction relating to the Question:

1) How to lowercase the column names in the DataFrame.

This is How you will do..

```
>>> df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

>>> df
  my_col   <-- Column name changed to lowercase
0    ONE
1    Two
2  Three
3   Four
```

2) How to lowercase the column values in the DataFrame.
 So, getting you column names to be into lowercase you don't need loop Just do like below..

```
>>> df.MY_COL.str.lower()
0      one
1      two
2    three
3     four
Name: MY_COL, dtype: object
```

OR

```
>>> df['MY_COL'].str.lower()
0      one
1      two
2    three
3     four
Name: MY_COL, dtype: object
```

**Example DataFrame:**

```
>>> df
  MY_COL
0    ONE
1    Two
2  Three
3   Four
```

However Query about `[]` , The part in square brackets is called a list comprehension List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists,  refer to the [Doc Listcomp](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score -1):

because df.columns is a list

Index(['something', 'other', ...],
      dtype='object')